# How to solve variable value in definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a definite integral:

$$\int_{-1}^3(a-x)dx = 12$$

I need to find the value of constant $a$ so that equation is true. Here is what I have tried:

First integrate using the exponent function integration formula:

$$\frac12a^2-\frac12x^2+C$$
Then form the equation:
$$f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a) = 12$$
Write the equation:
$$\frac12a^2-\frac123^2-\frac12a^2-\frac12(-1)^2 = 12$$
Multiply both sides by $2$:
$$a^2-3^2-a^2-(-1)^2=24$$
This however, is not true as it would result in $-10=24$ and $a$ would be completely lost. Could I have some advise?

Comment: Double-check your indefinite integral: remember you're integrating with respect to $x,$ so $\int a dx \neq \frac12 a^2 + C.$ This is a common mistake when dealing with constants that look like variables, or have special symbols like $\pi$.

Comment: What a beginner mistake... thank you! The value of $a$ is $4.25$ isn't it?

Comment: Not quite what I get, but I think I see where your issue is. Double-check your signs, particularly there's a nonzero chance you might've done $(-1)^2 = -1$ on accident

Comment: After integrating and multiplying both sides by $2$ I get $6a-3^2+2a-1=24$ Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes: starting from the form $F(b) - F(a)$ and plugging in we should get $(3a - \frac12 3^2) - (-a - \frac12 (-1)^2),$ and multiplying through by $2$ we should get $(6a - 3^2) - (-2a - (-1)^2).$ Note that there's a double negative on the $1$ now, that's the issue. (sorry for not mentioning before, as this was evident in the answer to begin with, I was focused on the antiderivative issue)

Comment: Now I get $a=16/8=2$ It seems that I had some basic mistake with brackets.

Comment: I think you dropped the factor of $2$ somewhere now: go back to $6a - 3^2 + 2a + 1 = 24 \Rightarrow 8a - 8 = 24$

Comment: Oh yes, had another sign error... $32/8=4$ sounds about right?

Comment: That should be right, yes

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to @Stephen Donovan, here are the correct steps for anyone who might run into same problem. $a$ is constant, not variable, so

$$\int(a-x)dx = ax-\frac12x^2 + C$$

Using the rule $f(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$ we can create equation:
$$(3a-\frac123^2)-(-a-\frac12(-1)^2) = 12$$

Multiply both sides by two and simplify:
$$(6a-3^2)-(-2a-(-1)^2)=24$$
$$8a = 32$$
$$a=4$$